# Why aren't the Standard Model predictions of $R(D)$ and $R(D^\ast)$ equal to 1?

Tags: particle-physics, experimental-physics, standard-model, observables, large-hadron-collider

The observables $R_K$ and $R_{K^\ast}$ are defined as

$$R_{K,K^*}(q_a^2, q_b^2) = \frac{\int_{q_a^2}^{q_b^2} \frac{d \Gamma (B^{(+,0)} \rightarrow K^{(+, \ast 0)} \mu^+ \mu^- )}{dq^2} dq^2}{\int_{q_a^2}^{q_b^2} \frac{d \Gamma (B^{(+,0)} \rightarrow K^{(+, \ast 0)} e^+ e^- )}{dq^2} dq^2}.$$

Since in the Standard Model (SM) we have Lepton Universality (LU), the SM prediction for these observables is very close to $1$.

The observables $R(D)$ and $R(D^\ast)$ are defined as $$R(D^{(\ast)}) = \frac{\mathcal{B} \left(\bar B \rightarrow D^{(\ast)} \tau^- \bar \nu_\tau \right)}{\mathcal{B} \left(\bar B \rightarrow D^{(\ast)} \ell^- \bar \nu_\ell \right)}.$$

Due to LU, shouldn't we expect the predictions for these observables by the SM to be close to $1$? What is so different between $R_K$ and $R_{K^\ast}$ and $R(D)$ and $R(D^\ast)$ for their SM predictions to be that different?

Comment: masses are not universal

Answer (score 2):

> Due to Lepton Universality, shouldn't we expect the predictions for these observables by the SM to be close to $1$? What is so different between $R_K$ and $R_{K^\ast}$ and $R(D)$ and $R(D^\ast)$ for their SM predictions to be that different?

@anna already answered your question: the rates involved in such ratios have an SM "universal" part positing all three leptons couple in such weak decays equally ("universal"), even though, given their different masses, they enter differently in the phase-space phase of the decay, providing a calculable "non-universal" part, which needs to be carefully taken out for each lepton, to leave the "ought-to-be-universal-or-not" coupling parts to be compared. (Actually, the situation is messier, as the quark masses affect the way the weak matrix elements hadronize through non-perturbative QCD effects, estimated on the lattice.)

A typical rate, taken from a standard [review](https://doi.org/10.1038/nature22346), with  regrets for my  work-shy failure to MathJax it, is [image: rate]

Here the non-universal phase-space factor is different for each lepton, but it is so simple to account for, that the authors lump it with the "old hat" universal part! So you have to struggle to pull out the (dominant!) non-universal parts, so as to focus on the delicate "should-be-universal" parts containing the sought-after new physics. If you don't, you get something like

[image: ratio] etc.

To  crudely address your comparison question to K-meson ratios, you just need to consider the fact that the energy available to phase-space kinematics of the decays to Kaons is, crudely, in MeV, 4400, of which the μ versus e masses difference is less than 5%; in contrast to that for the decay to  $D$s, which is  3400, where the mass of the τ is half of it,  contrasted to the negligible mass of the e,   1/2 MeV.  See how it almost gets you to the above, properly integrated?